# Can I ask for cash back in a grocery store in Dubai as it's done in the US?

Tags: money, shopping, dubai

I try to be more precise in the question.

Can I walk in a grocery store in Dubai and after buying some stuff ask for withdraw cash by paying with card as it's done in the US supermarkets?

Comment: Even if cashback services were available, they are in many countries restricted to domestic bank cards and cannot be used with foreign credit or debit cards because of the much higher fees for international card transactions.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo ok, thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: I'm not sure how it is in the US, but in Australia you can do this with ATM/EFTPOS/debit cards but not with credit cards. Other countries may also differentiate on these or other reasons.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo I have used my cards in the US many times and got cash back with no problems.

Comment: @HeidelBerGensis You have gotten cashback in the US with a foreign card? That's wonderful news because I tried to find that for a long time. Was this a MasterCard/Visa? In which store did this work?

Comment: @neo It's either a visa or a Cirus debit card, can't remember where but I did it a few times, maybe Walmart..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As of now, there's no cash back service in the UAE. There are talks about this every now and then in the GCC region, but so far it's not implemented.